# $ABCD$ is a parallelogram with perimeter $P_{ABCD}=26$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

$ABCD$ is a parallelogram $(AB\parallel CD,AB>BC)$ with perimeter $P_{ABCD}=26$. If the inscribed circle of triangle $BCD$ has a radius $R=\sqrt3$ and $\measuredangle ADC=120^\circ$, find the sides of the parallelogram.

[image]

Let's $AB=a, BC=b, (a>b)$. Then from the given perimeter, we have $2(a+b)=26\Rightarrow a+b=13,$ so basically we need just one more equality in terms of $a$ and $b$ to solve the problem for the sides of the parallelogram.

My intuition tells me that we should get it from the triangle $BCD$ as we can solve it (we have two sides $a$ and $b$, the radius of the inscribed circle $R=\sqrt3$ and the angle $\measuredangle BCD=60^\circ$). By saying we can solve it, I mean we can find every element of the triangle in terms of $a$ and $b$. I am not sure what to use, though. By the cosine rule $$BD^2=a^2+b^2-ab$$ I tried to use areas, but it didn't work: $$S_{\triangle BCD}=\dfrac12ab\sin60^\circ=\dfrac{\sqrt3}{4}ab\\p_{\triangle BCD}=\dfrac{a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab}}{2};S_{\triangle BCD}=\dfrac{a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab}}{2}\sqrt3$$ It isn't a very clever idea, right? What else can we use?

Comment: You're on the right track.  Continue by equating the two expressions for the area, and manipulate algebraically.  You will end up with a simple expression involving $a$ and $b$, which you can combine with $a + b = 13$ to obtain $a$ and $b$.

Comment: $CO$ is the angle bisector of $\angle BCD=60^\circ$, then $CM = \frac{\sqrt3}{\tan (60^\circ/2)} = 3$. By considering the other two tangent points of the incircle, find $BD = a+b-2\cdot 3 = 7$, and perimeter $P_{\triangle BCD} = a+b + BD = 20$. And you already know how to find the exact area of $\triangle BCD$ from $P_{\triangle BCD}$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-You have $BD^2=a^2+b^2-ab=(a+b)^2-3ab$ and
$(a+b+BD)\sqrt3=ab\sin(60^{\circ})=ab\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}$. Since you have the sum and the product of $a$ and $b$ you get an equation of the second degree whose root are $a$ and $b$ so you are done.